# StateSave Not Working in External Filter on Yajra Datatable

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I use Yajra Datatable to display the Admin list and use StateSave to remain in pagination / sorting. If stateSave is only used for pagination and sorting it still works. but if used for Filter (Ex Filter by Name, Phone or Email) stateSave does't work. are there other functions besides stateSave?

Here is a screenshot of the filter
[image]

Here is Datatable

```
 $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
    $('#datatable').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        stateSave : true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        ajax: "{{ route('admin.table') }}",
        columns: [
            {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'id', searchable: false, orderable: false},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'city', name: 'city'},
            {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
            {data: 'phone', name: 'phone'},
            {data: 'level', name: 'level'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', searchable: false, orderable: false}
        ]
    }).on('processing.dt', function (e, settings, processing) {
                if (processing) {
                    $('#datatable').hide();
                    $('#loading').show();
                } else {
                    $('#datatable').show();
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
        });

    $(document).on('click', '.filter', function() {
        filter();
    });

    function filter() {
        var name      = $('#name').val();
        var email      = $('#email').val();
        var phone   = $('#phone').val();
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';

        var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            stateSave:true,
            destroy: true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "lengthChange": false,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ route('admin.table') }}",
                type: 'get',
                data: function(d) {
                    d.name = name;
                    d.email = email;
                    d.phone = phone;
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'id', searchable: false, orderable: false},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'city', name: 'city'},
                {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                {data: 'phone', name: 'phone'},
                {data: 'level', name: 'level'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', searchable: false, orderable: false}
            ]


        });

        var state = table.state.loaded();
        if (state) {
            table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
                var colSearch = state.columns[colIdx].search;

                if (colSearch.search) {
                    $('input', table.column(colIdx).footer()).val(colSearch.search);
                }
            });

            table.draw();
        }

    }
```

Thanks for Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
    HTML PART



    <div class="box-body table-responsive">
    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Level</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <thead class="transparent-bg">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ["class" => "search-input-text form-control", "data-column" => 1, "placeholder" => 'name',"size"=>"15"]) !!}
        <a class="reset-data" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th>
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ["class" => "search-input-text form-control", "data-column" => 3, "placeholder" => 'email',"size"=>"15"]) !!}
        <a class="reset-data" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
      </th>
      <th>
        {!! Form::text('phone', null, ["class" => "search-input-text form-control", "data-column" => 4, "placeholder" => 'phone',"size"=>"15"]) !!}
        <a class="reset-data" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
</div>

    SCRIPT PART
    <script>

    (function () {
    var dataTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,

    ajax: {
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      url: '{{ route("admin.table") }}',
      type: 'post',
    },
    columns: [
    {data: null, searchable: false, sortable: false},
    {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
    {data: 'city', name: 'city'},
    {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
    {data: 'phone', name: 'phone'},
    {data: 'level', name: 'level'},
    {data: 'actions', name: 'actions', searchable: false, sortable: false, "width": "20%"}
    ],
    // order: [[7, "desc"]],
    searchDelay: 500,
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
     $("td:nth-child(1)", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex + 1);
     return nRow;
    }
    });
    Backend.DataTableSearch.init(dataTable);
     })();
    </script>
```

Comment: is this placed on Filter () or datatable on which to display the whole data?